# Systemverilog expansion rule

Tags: system-verilog, expansion

When I review some codes, I found something strange.
It seems that it comes from expansion and operation priority.
(I know that because "sig" is declared with 'signed', $signed is not necessary and '-sig' is correct one, anyway..)

```
reg signed [9:0] sig;
reg signed [11:0] out;

initial
begin
    $monitor ("%0t] sig=%0d, out=%0h", $time, sig, out);
    sig = 64;
    out = $signed(-sig);
#1
    out = -$signed(sig);
#1
    sig = -512;
    out = $signed(-sig);
#1
    out = -$signed(sig);
#1
$finish;
end
```

Simulation result for above codes is,

```
0] sig=64, out=-64
2] sig=-512, out=-512
3] sig=-512, out=512
```

When sig=-512, I expected that 10 bits sig would be expanded to 12bits before negation, but it was expanded after negation.
Therefore negation of -512 was still -512, and after expansion, it had a -512.
I guess "$signed() blocks expansion..Any idea what happens??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `-512` and `512` are identical numbers in 10-bit represenntation. 10 bits can actually only hold signed values from -512  to 511. In this scheme negation of `-512` should work weirdly, not mentioned in lrm, at least i was not able to locate anything related. This is probably an undefined behavior.

However, it is logical to assume that in this scheme in order to represent a negated value of '-512' just removing signess is sufficient. It seems that all commercial compilers in eda playground do this. So, a result of the unaray `-` operator in this case will be **unsigned** value of 512.

So, in `out = $signed(-(-512))` the negation operator returns an unsigned value of 512 and it gets converted to a signed by the system task. Therefore, it gets sign extended in out.

`out = -$signed(-512)` for the same reason the outermost negation operator returns an unsigned value of 512. No sign extension happens here.

You can again make it signed by enclosing in yet another $signed as `out = $signed(-$signed(-512))`

Comment: Well.. '-' arithmetic operator is a unary operator but not a reduction operator and my understanding is that only reduction operator returns unsigned value. Similar example is A = 3'b100 ; B= 3'b100;  out = $signed(A + B); // logic signed [7:0] out; then out is '0' and it seems that inside of $signed forms a single expression and expanded after evaluation.

Comment: reduction operators retur 1-bit values

Comment: Yes, and its attribute is unsigned when it is used in expression. The systemverilog LRM says "Comparison and reduction operator results are unsigned, regardless of the operands." anyway..